# Are there other very common non-invented English names in the Star Wars films other than Ben, Luke and Owen?

Tags: star-wars

George Lucas created a lot of names (e.g. Obi-Wan, Lando, Qui-Gon, Yoda). Lucas used Ben and Luke among all sorts of made up, Star Wars galaxy names. (I don't think Leia was at all common as a name before this and I think Han was made up).

In the Star Wars film series, what other non-made-up, very commonly used in English character names are there?

(I am not going to make this statistics based if I can help it, but Luke, Ben and Owen are very popular and clearly used regularly over a good period of time in English-speaking countries. Cody is another good example).

Comment: Ben(jamin) and Luke are, respectively, Hebrew and Greek names that have been co-opted into common use in England and America. Do you just mean "*non-made-up*" names?

Comment: In EU/Legends? Oooooh that probably is a long list. @Richard, I dare you :)

Comment: Hmm. Seems very open-list-y for my tastes.

Comment: @Richard - OK, let me try :)

Comment: @Richard yes that's what I meant. Non-made-up. If there is a long list in the EU (I don't remember many besides Jacen if that counts) perhaps I should limit it to film names and go from there?

Comment: Still gonna be a long one

Comment: how common do you want for it to count as common? What about [English spellings of foreign names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_(name))

Comment: @Mike Edenfield I *was* interested in truly common (e.g. I hadn't thought of Owen or Cody and they certainly count) though I am quite fascinated by what's coming up here. I may be in trouble for uncertainty here! I'm actually quite surprised it wasn't a dupe despite searching for one and obviously not finding one.

Comment: @ThruGog - I personally think you should limit it to the films. If you go with the EU, there are literally tens of thousands of names.

Comment: I agree; as it, I think this one is too broad, because people will just keep coming along with more EU stuff with random names. If you restricted it to just what's been shown on-screen, for example, I'd retract my close vote.

Comment: You may also want to state what counts as "common". I personally favour something like [this](http://www.babynamewizard.com/voyager#prefix=&sw=both&exact=false)

Comment: Closed as primarily opinion,  without a definition of what counts as an English name. Also

Comment: @Mike Edenfield It has been changed in the way you suggested. I'm not sure I'm going to define common or English in a way that satisfies everyone but it has been limited to films only.

Comment: Leah is a fairly common rendering of a common Hebrew Bible name (one of the wives of Jacob) that is pronounced essentially the same as Leia by many.

Answer (score 10):

Based largely on [this list of SW characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Wars_characters) and taking only those who

- Featured in the movies.
- Whose names hit [the top 500 most popular baby names](http://www.behindthename.com/) in the US or UK in the last 50 years.

Then there there are a considerable number of characters whose names seem to fit the description "*common English*"

### Phantom Menace

> **Dexter** Jettster
>   **Gavyn** Sykes
>   **Jocasta** Nu
>   **Ric** Olié
>   **Ben** Quadrinaros

### Attack of the Clones

> **Coleman** Trebor

### The Clone Wars

> **Mina**

### Revenge of the Sith

> **Coleman** Kcaj
>   **Cody**
>   **Janus** Greejatus

### A New Hope

> **Cornelius** Evazan
>   **Wes** Janson
>   **Owen** Lars
>   **Derek** "Hobbie" Klivian
>   **John** Branon

### Empire Strikes Back

> **Maximilian** Veers

### Return of the Jedi

> **Max** Rebo

### The Force Awakens

> **Finn**

### Rogue One: A Star Wars Story

> **Bodhi** Rook

### Solo: A Star Wars Story

> **Tobias** Beckett

You may also want to note that **Ezra** Bridger is the star of Star Wars: Rebels.

Comment: I should get a +1 just for having Uncle Owen in mine...

Comment: Oh, you've got him now too. :-)

Comment: @Praxis - doesn't Mace Windu beat anyone else :))) Because he's Mace MF Windu!!

Comment: @DVK : Hehehe, well, when you put it that way...

Comment: @DVK - Mace isn't a common name.

Comment: @Richard - if you limit to 500, perhaps. But popular enough that there are a bunch of people with that surname (#2734 out of 150436, Top 2%), some with that first name, and even several fictional characters of that name.

Comment: @DVK - Mace has never been in the top 1000 names in the UK or US; https://www.ssa.gov/

Comment: @Richard  - given absence of definition in the question, it's not worth arguing about. If OP doesn't think Mace is popular enough they'll say so

Comment: @DVK I actually taught a boy named Mace. I think he's young enough to have been named after Windu. Not sure it's common though, but never mind!

Comment: Sems like a bunch of folks missed Padme.  Padme is a fairly common Indian name.

Comment: @PaulTIKI - OP was after English names.

Comment: @Valorum  Janus and Bodhi aren't exactly English.  Janus is the name of an old Roman god (the god of gateways). Bodhi comes from Sanskrit.  I mention Padme because once upon a time India was a British Colony.  In Harry Potter, Padme is Harry's (or maybe Ron's) date for the ball during book 4.  I must mention that there is a spelling difference.  HP's Padma is spelled with an 'a' at the end

Comment: @PaulTIKI - Indeed, but Padmé has never breached the top 500 names in the US or UK which is the benchmark that I've used.

Comment: @Valorum  Fair enough.  I'm sort of surprised though.  We should be grateful that no Star Wars names included Lemonjello :)

Answer (score 6):

## Yes

- **Uncle Owen**
- **Ezra**, a character on *Star Wars Rebels*
- **Cody**, a Stormtrooper commander in *Revenge of the Sith*
- **Finn**, a (nick)name given to FN-2187 in *The Force Awakens*
- **Fox**, a Stormtrooper commander in *Clone Wars*
- **Wes**, a rebel pilot in *Empire Strikes Back*
- **Karina**, Queen of Geonosis in *Clone Wars*
- **Max Rebo**, music combo leader in Jabba's palace in *Return of the Jedi*

All of the above are canon, but I can't help but also mention **Kyle Katarn**, the protagonist of the *Jedi Knight* video games!

Comment: I forgot about Cody! Will he be the only character in Lucas-penned films other than Ben and Luke?

Comment: Finn is his nickname.

Comment: @Richard - well, technically, it's his adopted name. So I think that counts.

Comment: @Richard : I know.  I've seen the film twice.  That's why I say "given to FN-2187".  It's still an English name --- that's the point.

Comment: Long live Kyle Katarn! Did anyone else used to spend ages walking around in third person view while crouching in *Jedi Knight II*? Such an odd visual.

Comment: @ThruGog : Yes!  Brings back memories.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

[DC]=Disney canon. [LC]=Lucas G/T pre-disney. [EU] obvious and default

- [GC] [Mace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mace) Windu. I think I can now safely stop the listing, nobody beats Mace. It's more popular as a surname (#2734 out of 150436, Top 2%) than a given name, but used as first name too.
- [DC] Norra Wexley from canon *Aftermath* novel has a typical Muggle name ([Norah](http://nameberry.com/babyname/Norah))
- Winter (Leia's Alderaanian aide, or D'Artagnan's antagonist Milady Winter?)
- [GC] General **Maximilian** Veers
- [GC] [Bail](http://www.thinkbabynames.com/meaning/1/Bail) Antilles and Bail Organa
- [GC] Jedi Coleman Trebor (AotC) has a first name that's a popular English surname.
- Bria Tharen (Han's first gf)
- Ailyn Vel (Boba Fett's daughter) is a changed name from Eileen
- [Tavion](http://www.sheknows.com/baby-names/name/tavion) is a Scottish name (Tavion Axmis)
- Jenna Zan Arbor
- Solo children are named Jacen and Jaina.
- Stass Allie has a russian male name (Stas) despite being a female Jedi
- Demetrius Zaarin (clearly a version of Greek Dimitrius)
- Zorba the <strike>Greek</strike> Hutt
- Tahiri Vella's first name is a [popular last name](https://lastnames.myheritage.com/last-name/tahiri)
- Captain Gregar Typho

Comment: Actually Wexley sounds a bit wizardly ( !muggle ) :)

Comment: You can have my +1 for using Muggle to sensibly describe what I so struggled to explain!

Comment: I also saw that Gial is supposed to be real name but can't find a reference for that (that's Admiral Ackbar's first name)

Comment: @DVK : OP is looking for names used in English-speaking world.

Comment: @Praxis - there's plenty of Stases in NY, I work with two. Virtually every name in English is borrowed from some other source (rather, stolen).

Comment: @DVK : Fair enough...

Comment: None of these (bar Norah) are *common* **English** names.

Comment: I'm happy to see names from other cultures, but I imagine it was a coincidence. @Praxis not sure that Fox exactly counts in my humble opinion!

Comment: @ThruGog : Fox Mulder!!

Comment: @Praxis There's no way Fox was on his birth certificate!

Comment: Ummm....I didn't downvote you.  I only downvote questions / answers unsuitable for this site.  Why did you assume I did?

Comment: I just upvoted you.  There's still that pesky downvote.  Not mine...

Comment: @Praxis - ah, it was same time as your comment, never mind then, sorry. I know who it is then. Par for the course

Comment: @ThruGog - Fox has never featured in the [top 1000](http://www.babynamewizard.com/baby-name/boy/fox) baby names in the US

Comment: Fox Mulder's name is William :)

Comment: @DVK : I thought it was his middle name. (His father's first name was William.)  And no worries about the downvote thing...I try to be mindful of these coincidences --- when I see a downvote come in at the same time I leave a comment, I usually include a "By the way, I didn't downvote you..." disclaimer.  But I didn't even notice the downvote come in this time.

Comment: @Praxis - yah we were comment-spamming like crazy.

Comment: +1 for Bria Tharen, that was one of my favorite books from the EU.

Answer (score -2):

Deleted scenes from A New Hope, but one of Luke’s Friends was Cammy Marstrap and Han was with a girl named Jenny in the original Cantina shots. Another Cantina patron is called BoShek.

In Empire there’s a rebel in Echo Base named Toryn Farr. Carlist Riekaan is close enough to Carl that it might be a related name in a different language.

One of the dancers in Jabba’s Palace is called Jes. The female security in the red outfit was called Celina Marniss or Melina Carniss (I don’t remember since Mara Jade used the version with switched first letters as an alias once.)

Comment: I fail to see how this answer the question asked. BoShek, Toryn and Carlist are hardly common English names